# PHP foreach loop through array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a fairly big array that I source from Facebook:

```
array(25) {
  [0]=>
  array(14) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(31) "245226895508982_651884328176568"
    ["from"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Madeleine BjÃ¶rs"
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "100002249777453"
    }
    ["to"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["data"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["name"]=>
          string(31) "Wohnung/WG in MÃ¼nchen gesucht!"
          ["id"]=>
          string(15) "245226895508982"
        }
      }
    }
```

Now what I want to do is go through the array and save ID, name and various other information from that array into a mysql database. However, to understand how to target specific information I tried to echo the data first.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'), true);

foreach($data as $item) {
      echo $item['id'];
      echo '<pre>'; var_dump($item);
}
```

This PHP code is based on various posts on Stackoverflow, however, the code returns nothing. May you please help me to target the arrays appropriately? You may check the enire array here: http://faculty-fight.de/milliondollaridea/facebook_session.php

Cheers!

Comment: Getting remote files in `file_get_contents` may be blocked in the `php.ini` settings. Have you checked if `$data` is filled using `print_r($data)` or such?

Comment: you can use foreach($arrayName as $key=>$value) for each diamention

Comment: @Etherealone if you check the link http://faculty-fight.de/milliondollaridea/facebook_session.php it shows you how the array looks like and it is indeed filled.

Comment: @RahulKumar Even with your example I cannot seem to target the arrays. May you give me an example?

Comment: @John Any chance your script does some invalid actions afterwards and no output is done due to error reporting flags?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$subArray)
{
     foreach($subArray as $subKey=>subSubArray)
     {
          if(is_array($subSubArray))
          {
               foreach($subSubArray as $subSubKey=>$value)
               {
                      if(is_array($value))
                      { 
                         foreach($value as $valueKey=>$subValue)
                         { 
                              /* your code /*
                         }
                      }
               }
           }
     }
```

you can check for id values for example for 1st loop (if($subKey == "to")).

Comment: This is no solution to the problem in the question.

Comment: this can be impelemted.. otherwise sterilize the object and then unsterlize

Comment: Yeah I don't really get it :(